# How to calculate per pcs production time using a formula in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

5 processes (tasks) are involved to make a toy car.

How to calculate using a formula, the total number of minutes it would take a worker to complete each task to finish a toy car.

```
task 1#  5.0/hour
task 2#  6.0/hour
task 3#  7.5/hour
tas  4#  3.0/hour 
task 5#  9.0/hour
```

Answer (score 2):

You first have to calculate the number of minutes it task to complete a task, by dividing 60 (the number of minutes in an hour) by it. Then you can take the sum:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur reply. But is there any formula which produce the result without creation of 3rd or 4th coloumn. Like "SUMPRODUCT" formula.

Comment: Not that I know of. You can of course just hide the column if you don't want to show the intermediate results.

Comment: Of course, you can use `=60/B2+60/B3+60/B4+60/B5+60/B6` but that's just more awkward.

Comment: Thanks Sir. yes its awkward, but working. If there any standard formula, I mean u found then pls post again.

Comment: @Washim `=SUMPRODUCT(60/B2:B6)`

Comment: @ScottCraner right, that does the job. You should post that as an answer.